# Apache Flink - DataSet API - How to group n results together

Tags: batch-processing, apache-flink

We are doing batch processing using Apache Flink(1.4.2) and for performance reasons instead of outputting each item directly we want to group 100 items before outputting it.

If we were to use the DataStream API we would be able to use something like tumbling windows (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#tumbling-windows)

But this is not available when doing batch processing.

Is it possible to do this using the DataSet Api perhaps through some group / reduce function?

Comment: Should work. Try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the records can be arbitrarily batched together, I would not use `groupBy`, `reduce`, or `groupReduce` because they would unnecessarily shuffle and sort the `DataSet`.

Instead you can use a `MapPartitionFunction` to batch records together. A `MapPartition` receives an iterator over all records of a partition and can emit records through a collector. Since it just consumes records without reorganizing them (shuffle, sort), it is very efficient.